# Calculate average of two columns based on the availability data (missing or NaN value of those columns) in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, mean

I have df as shown below

df:

```
player    goals_oct     goals_nov
messi     2             4
neymar    2             NaN
ronaldo   NaN           3
salah     NaN           NaN
levenoski 2             2
```

Where I would like to calculate the average goal scored by each player. Which is the average of `goals_oct` and `goals_nov` when both the data are available else the available column, if both not available then NaN

Expected output

```
player    goals_oct     goals_nov   avg_goals
messi     2             4           3
neymar    2             NaN         2 
ronaldo   NaN           3           3
salah     NaN           NaN         NaN
levenoski 2             0           1
```

I tried the below code, but it did not works

```
conditions_g = [(df['goals_oct'].isnull() and df['goals_nov'].notnull()), 
              (df['goals_oct'].notnull() and df['goals_nov'].isnull())]

choices_g = [df['goals_nov'], df['goals_oct']]

df['avg_goals']=np.select(conditions_g, choices_g, default=(df['goals_oct']+df['goals_nov'])/2)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply use [`mean(axis=1)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html). It will skip NaNs:

```
columns = df.columns[1:] # all columns except the first
df['avg_goal'] = df[columns].mean(axis=1)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
      player  goals_oct  goals_nov  avg_goal
0      messi        2.0        4.0       3.0
1     neymar        2.0        NaN       2.0
2    ronaldo        NaN        3.0       3.0
3      salah        NaN        NaN       NaN
4  levenoski        2.0        2.0       2.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this it will work

```py
df["avg_goals"] = np.where(df.goals_oct.isnull(),
                           np.where(df.goals_nov.isnull(), np.NaN, df.goals_nov),
                           np.where(df.goals_nov.isnull(), df.goals_oct, (df.goals_oct + df.goals_nov) / 2))
```

if you want to consider `0` as `empty value` then you can `convert 0 to np.NaN` and try above statement it will work